# Start a bounty with the intention of giving it to an existing answer?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15647843/nsviewcontroller-on-mac-os-x-10-4) a while ago and the provided answer is really a lot more comprehensive than I was looking for and think it is worth more than just the 25 rep I gave him with a +1 and an “accept”. Is it wrong to start a bounty with the intention of giving it straight to this answer when all applicable timeouts have lapsed? I guess what I'm asking is it's not breaking rules or etiquette?

Comment: There's even an "award existing answer" option...

Comment: Go ahead. There even is a bounty reason specifically for that.

Comment: I can't see the options yet because the question isn't eligible for bounty, I need to wait another 22 hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) (emphasis added)

> **Can I award a bounty to an old answer?**
>
> Yes, you can award your bounty to any answer on the question. **This makes it possible for users to reward particularly good answers with more rep than a standard upvote would provide.**